# How do I nest lists?

Tags: basecamp

Is there a way to

- nest lists
- in Basecamp

  - like this?

I sometimes get it to work by copy-pasting, but that makes it really hard to modify.  Or is that purely a bug and it doesn't "work" at all?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the markup for writeboards and messages and such it is:

```
* First level bullet point  
** Second level bullet point  
*** Third level bullet point
```

This will show up as:

> - First level bullet point
>
>   - Second level bullet point
>
>     - Third level bullet point

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the new Basecamp version, you will need to use Google Docs, Word, or some other document formatting tool to get indented lists for now.